# Order result resolved via resolver in graphql + apollo server + nodejs

Tags: node.js, graphql, prisma, apollo-server, prisma-graphql

I am trying to order an array returned by resolver in GraphQL.
I can only think of way of ordering data using DB Query, but how can we order data that GraphQL resolves using its resolver functions?

Below is my Query resolver:

```
getAllNotifications: (
      _parent,
      _args: { authorId: string },
      context: Context
    ) => {
      return context.prisma.blog.findMany({
        where: {
          authorId: _args.authorId,
        },
        orderBy: {
          created_at: "desc",
        },
      });
    },
```

And my query:

```
query Query($authorId: String) {
  getAllNotifications(authorId: $authorId) {
    title
    comment {
      id
      created_at
    }
  }
}
```

And result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getAllNotifications": [
      {
        "title": "First Ride! ",
        "comment": [ <--- I am trying to order this comment array using created_at date
          {
            "id": "cl8afqaqx001209jtxx7mt5h6",
            "created_at": "2022-09-20T16:53:07.689Z"
          },
          {
            "id": "cl8agiq71001509l27or7oxyd",
            "created_at": "2022-09-20T17:15:14.077Z"
          },
          {
            "id": "cl8ahmvrm003109l8dp684bn6",
            "created_at": "2022-09-20T17:46:27.538Z"
          },
          {
            "id": "cl99kj24p002609iajdbpycg0",
            "created_at": "2022-10-15T06:59:24.169Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I didn't found anything in Graphql docs regarding ordering data returned by resolver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL doesn't have functions for selection and ordering, those are jobs that resolvers must do.

Add a resolver for `comment` that sorts the `comment` array. Your existing sort just sorts based on the `created_at` date of the post.